# git pull and push denied, nothing works anymore

Tags: git

I have an respository that needs to be updated.

However pull results in an error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
```

Actually I want them to be overwritten ...

If I try to push I also get an error

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart.
```

How can I get around this problem?

EDIT:
git status:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: You must have reset or amended your last commit

Comment: If you really want them to be overridden you can try `git pull origin --force`

Comment: What does `git status` show you?

Answer (score 2):

1. Clean your working tree first by `Stash` or `Commit`. I prefer stash if you are middle of any change.

   ```
   $ git add .
   $ git stash save 'message'
   ```
2. Pull remote branch changes.

   ```
   $ git pull origin <branch-name>
   ```
3. Retrieve the changes from Stash.

   ```
   $ git stash apply
   ```
4. Resolve conflicts if occurs.

   ```
   $ git status         # find the conflicted file(s) -> red color files normally
   # resolve conflicts
   ```
5. Add, Commit, Push to remote.

   ```
   $ git add .
   $ git commit -m 'message'
   $ git push origin HEAD
   ```
6. If all stuff goes perfect then clean the stash. [optional]

   ```
   $ git stash drop
   ```

Comment: @Matthias Pospiech, Does it work for you or any other error?

Answer (score 0):

stash your changes, pull down code, unstash changes, commit, push, boom. done.

or

in your console just type git pull --ff-only.

This will fast-forward your local copy of the branch so it's the same as the remote.